# Generics in .net 2.0 : Using a Where class on a class definition

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

During the preparation for "Programing in C#" Certification from [this](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-483-programming-in-c-sharp-9780735676824) book at objective 2.1 where the following code is shown for generic types:

```
class MyClass<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyProperty = new T();
    }

    T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I know what generic type is and why we need it, but can any one explain this confusing code and how we can use this with any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't understand this part:

```
where T:class,new()
```

This says that `T` must be a reference type (i.e. class) and it must have a default constructor (a constructor with no arguments). This means that `T` can't be `int` because it is a struct. It also can't be `StreamReader` because it does not have a default constructor.

Why is this useful?

Some things can only be used with reference types but not value types e.g. `as`. And because you said `T` must have a default constructor, you can do this:

```
public MyClass()
{
    MyProperty = new T();
}
T MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Since `T` must have a default constructor, you can call `new T()`.

Comment: Yeah that's the first part which confuse me(i.e where T:class,new() )
Now as per your explanation suppose we have Person class like below
class Person
    {
        Person()
        {
            this.PersonName = "Jack";
        }
        public  string PersonName{ get;set; }
    }

How we can use that generic MyClass with this .

Comment: Since `Person` is a reference type (a class) and it has a default constructor. It can be used as a generic type parameter for `MyClass`. You can initialize an instance of it like this: `var obj = new MyClass<Person>()`. Now `obj.MyProperty` stores a person with a name of "Jack". @UsmanHayatKhan

Comment: You should include this into your answer, because it's probably the part that the OP didn't understand.